# How to perform text search with a comma in it with lucene query syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

The example text is like this `172.16.17.39:6693, 172.16.17.34:6693` or `172.16.17.39:6693, 172.16.17.34:6693, 172.16.17.34:6694`, I use `upstream_addr:"172.16.17.39:6693, 172.16.17.34:6693"` I can get the exact items, But when I use below methods:

`upstream_addr:","
upstream_addr:"\,"
upstream_addr:,
upstream_addr:\,
upstream_addr:','
upstream_addr:'\,'`

I get nothing back. I have no clue after I saw the [lucene query document](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) or the [elastic document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) several times.

Below is the example of the upstream_addr:

`upstream_addr:"172.16.6.133:6671, 172.16.6.134:6671, 172.16.6.176:6671"
upstream_addr:"172.16.6.111:6671"
upstream_addr:"172.16.6.134:6671, 172.16.6.176:6671"
upstream_addr:"172.16.6.111:6671, 172.16.6.134:6671, 172.16.6.176:6671"
upstream_addr:"172.16.6.176:6671"
upstream_addr:"172.16.6.176:6671, 192.168.0.127:6671"`

I need to get all the items with more than one ip:port pairs. I found all the items with more than one ip:port pairs contains a comma in it, so I want to get the items with comma in it.

Comment: you are using what ? elasticsearch ? how did you indexed the documents ?

Comment: you want to search for commas? are they not deleted by analyzer?

Comment: @danvasiloiu @Mysterion The is my Nginx log which has been changed to json format, I put them to my ElasticSearch cluster. If the upstream_addr contains a comma, the upstream server must have errors, I just want know the error logs. The log is somehow like this `{ "remote_addr": "117.136.86.165",
    "request": "POST /weather/pb/short/detail HTTP/1.1",
    "upstream_addr": "192.168.1.13:6694, 192.168.1.15:6694" }`
I got the above message from my Kibana's json view. I don't have much knoweledge about the ElasticSearch, I assume I indexed the documents by default.

Comment: like @Mysterion says.. the commas are deleted by the analyzer. you need to use a keyword tokenizer. i dont really get what you need to do

Comment: @ danvasiloiu I add some more info.